# How can I get the variables from other modules or classes?

Tags: python

First of all. I just want to thanks to you for helping me.

I have two Python Files(modules) named "select_main.py" and "select.py"
These are simple tkinter GUIs. In the "select_main.py" there are two Entries which I want to get variables.
In the "select.py" there are also two Entries which I want to deliver variables to "select_main.py"

but I always get errors some kind of "no attribute ..." and "not defined..."

How can I get the variables from sub GUI window to main.

select_main.py

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as ttk
from select import *


class main():
    def __init__(self, root):

        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Main")
        self.root.geometry("300x200+800+500")

        def pushButton_main():
            pop_1 = main_sel(Toplevel())

        def set_data(var1, var2):
            self.id = var1
            self.name = var2



        self.id = StringVar()
        self.name = StringVar()

        self.main_frame = Frame(self.root, bd=2, width=300, height=400, relief=GROOVE)
        self.main_frame.pack()

        self.lbl_ID = Label(self.main_frame, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), text="ID")
        self.lbl_ID.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, pady=2)
        self.txt_ID = Entry(self.main_frame, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), textvariable=id)
        self.txt_ID.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W, pady=2)

        self.lbl_Name = Label(self.main_frame, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), text="Name")
        self.lbl_Name.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, pady=2)
        self.txt_Name = Entry(self.main_frame, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), textvariable=self.name)
        self.txt_Name.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W, pady=2)

        self.btn_select = Button(self.main_frame, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), bd=2, width=6, height=2, text= "Search", justify=LEFT, command=pushButton_main)
        self.btn_select.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=1, pady=2, rowspan=2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    aplication = main(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

and select.py

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as ttk
import select_main

class main_sel():
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Sub")
        self.root.geometry("300x200+1000+500")

        var_id = StringVar()
        var_name = StringVar()

        def pushButton_sub():
            a = select_main.id
            b = select_main.name

            t1 = var_id.get() 
            t2 = var_name.get()

            a.set(t1)
            b.set(t2)

            win2.destroy()

        self.main_frame = Frame(self.root, bd=2, width=300, height=400, relief=GROOVE)
        self.main_frame.pack()

        self.lbl_ID = Label(self.main_frame, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), text="ID")
        self.lbl_ID.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, pady=2)
        self.txt_ID = Entry(self.main_frame, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), textvariable=var_id)
        self.txt_ID.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W, pady=2)

        self.lbl_Name = Label(self.main_frame, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), text="Name")
        self.lbl_Name.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, pady=2)
        self.txt_Name = Entry(self.main_frame, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), textvariable=var_name)
        self.txt_Name.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W, pady=2)

        self.btn_select = Button(self.main_frame, font=("arial", 10, "bold"), bd=2, width=6, height=2, text= "Input", justify=LEFT, command=pushButton_sub)
        self.btn_select.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=1, pady=2, rowspan=2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    aplication = main(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: So which of these two scripts are you running?  If you run `select_main.py`, and `import select`, then you can create an instance of `ms = select.main_sel()` and refer to variables within `ms`.

Comment: Yes. I am running with select_main.py. 
And I will try to make instance as you said. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think in the select_main.py you import select.py, and in select.py you import select_main.py, this causes the loop, and will be conflict. So You can try remove import select_main.py in select.py and try again. Be sure that no variable in select_main that needed in select.py. If there are any variables needed, just declare them in select.py.

Comment: Thank you for your advise. I will try that.